# Custom nginx auth header - without Authorization

Tags: nginx

I have a proxied nuxt app set up like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This works great. Now I want to restrict it for development purposes so only my team have access to it.

I cannot use IPs because some team members have dynamic IP. So I stumbled upon auth_basic and set it up by adding:

```
auth_basic           "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
```

This also works fine as far as restriction goes. The problem is that it uses the `Authorization` header and that interferes with our app's authentication mechanism.

Is there any way to make nginx use another header like maybe `X-Authorization`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has authentication mechanism , its better to control access from there among teams.

Pretty sure http_basic_auth works on standards. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2.

[RFC7234, section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2) says that requests/responses Authorization header MUST not be cached (except in specific circumstances).

[RFC7235, section 5.1.2, point 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-5.1.2) furthermore has this say to about NEW authentication schemes that use headers other than Authorization:

If you want auth on some specific paths, then

```
location /public/setup-steps {
       auth_basic           "Restricted";   
       auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/; 
}
```

Just remember to put this location before `/`.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response; i wanted to restrict access in that way because there are also public pages, not protected by auth

Comment: you can have nginx auth on public pages then , something like 
`location /public/setup-setup {
  auth_basic           "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd; 
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/;
}` . Just remember to up this location path before /

Comment: yes but even the public pages have different elements for logged vs guests :/